# Can backspace escape cancel a new-line escape?

Tags: c, terminal, newline, pty, backspace

I'm working with ubuntu.
Code:

```
printf("Hello\n\b world");
```

I get on terminal:

```
Hello
 world
```

Why does backspace not cancel the \n?
Is there a hierarchy in chars?

How can I delete special chars?

Comment: the behavior of `\b` depends on the terminal, but usually just go back to the previous character in the same line. If you already go to a new line then how can it know where to go back? You'll need to use ncurses or the terminal API to do that

Comment: Open a terminal window on your OS, press Enter, then start pressing Backspace. Most of the time you won't go back to the previous line, though there may exist some where you do. But what you expect is more of a feature of text editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question goes beyond the scope of the C language: `printf("Hello\n\b world");` outputs the bytes from the format string, possibly translated according to the text mode handling of newlines:

- on unix systems, the bytes are output to the system handle unmodified.
- on Microsoft legacy systems, the newline is converted to CR LF and the other bytes transmitted unmodified.

If the standard output is directed to a file, the file will contain the translation of the newline and a backspace (0x08 on most systems).

If the standard output goes to a terminal, the handling of the backspace special character is outside the program's control: the terminal (hardware, virtual, local or remote...) will perform its task as programmed and configured... Most terminals move the cursor left one position on whatever display they control, some erase the character at that position. If the cursor is already at column 1, it is again system dependent whether backspace moves the cursor back to the end of the previous line, whatever that means. Many systems don't do that and keep the cursor at column 1. This seems consistent with the behavior you observe.

Comment: Rather than saying the behavior of sending a character to a terminal is "system dependent", I'd say it's *outside the system's control*.  Many systems accept connections from terminals or terminal-emulation programs which may be produced by arbitrary outside suppliers.  If someone connects a terminal that triggers an air raid siren any time it receives a "!" character, and a program's output s directed to that terminal, `putchar('!'); fflush(stdout);` would trigger an air raid siren.

Comment: @supercat: The answer was somewhat confusing as *system* referred to the terminal, not the host OS... answer amended.

Answer (score 3):

Those escape sequences `\b` and `\n` represent [*control characters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).  A control character is a special character that, well, controls the behavior of the output device in some special way.  When you say

```
printf("A");
```

it prints the (ordinary) character `A` to the screen.  But when you say

```
printf("\n");
```

it doesn't print anything, instead it moves the cursor down to the beginning of the next line.

Now, the meaning of `\b` is *not* "cancel the character to the left".  The control character `\b` does not "cancel" anything.  What it does is just move the cursor one character to the left, if it can.  But if the cursor is already at the left edge, it probably can't.

Once upon a time, and especially when the output was going to a printer that actually printed on paper, it was common to do things like

```
printf("this is u\b_n\b_d\b_e\b_r\b_l\b_i\b_n\b_e\b_d\b_\n");
```

or

```
printf("this is b\bbo\bol\bld\bd\n");
```

to print underlined or bold words by overprinting.  These examples obviously rely on the move-one-to-the-left behavior of `\b`.  These examples prove that the behavior of `\b` is not anything like "canceling"!

It sounds like you think `\b` might somehow affect the string it's part of.
It sounds like you think `\b` might somehow be processed by your C compiler, or by the C library.
It sounds like you think that the string `"abc\bdef"` might get converted to `"abdef"`.
But none of these things is true.  The backspace character `\b` is interpreted by your screen or your printer, or whatever output device your program is "printing" to.  The interpretation of control characters like `\b` is mostly up to your output device.  It is mostly not a property of the C programming language.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the C standard says (in C 2018 5.2.2 2) about the new line character:

> Moves the active position to the initial position of the next line.

and backspace:

> Moves the active position to the previous position on the current line. If the active position is at the initial position of a line, the behavior of the display device is unspecified.

Note that the backspace character is not specified to erase a previous character. It is specified to cause a certain action on a display device.

Recall that C was developed in an era when teletypes and other physical printing devices were in common use. Many of these devices could only push the paper upward. Once a new line character caused the paper to be pushed upward, there was no way to move it downward again.

Additionally, some early video displays, or the software driving them, emulated physical printing and did not support going back a line, at least in some of their modes of operation.

On displays where one could move the cursor freely, it is not clear what a backspace from the beginning of a line should do. Consider a display which has 80 columns, numbered from 1 to 80, and the last line printed contained 40 characters, followed by a new line. When we backspace, we move the cursor back to that line, but which column do we move it to? Column 80, the last one of the display? Or column 40, the last one where something was printed? Different devices might handle this differently. Note that the latter choice requires the device to remember the length of each line, an added burden on early computing machinery. (My high school’s cheap display terminals did not have enough memory to remember all the text in a 24×80 display. I think it was only 1024 bytes, enough for 12.8 lines of 80 characters. If you wrote complete lines of text, it would scroll earlier lines off the display, keeping only the last 12.)

Because of these variations in behavior, the C standard did not specify the details of backspacing from the start of a line.

You ask about a “backspace escape” canceling a “new-line escape.” However, the escape sequences are irrelevant here; they are in a different layer of representation than the operations of the characters:

- Inside a string literal, `\b` and `\n` are escape sequences. As the compiler translates the program, it replaces these with a backspace character and a new line character. Then they are no longer escape sequences; they are simply characters in a string.
- When you write the characters with `printf`, they are transmitted as characters in a stream.
- When the characters are sent to a display device (because that is what the stream is connected to), they produce the actions in the 5.2.2 2 text cited above.